# Test to Compare Two Sets of Likert Questions

Tags: survey, likert

I have two sets of questions in a survey.

The first set is 6 Likert scales for how important a particular trait is for someone to be an elected official (How important is it that an elected representative be ambitious, for example).

The second set is the same 6 Likert scales for how well the respondent thinks the trait describes them (Are you ambitious, for example).

What I would like to know is the best way to determine, statistically, what proportion of the respondents consider themselves "qualified" to be an elected official (say, but saying 3/4ths of the traits they said were important are traits that they say describe them well.).

Hopefully that makes sense. I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking, but I just can't quite wrap my mind around how to approach this.